# Service Fabric stateful service no longer replicates

Tags: azure-service-fabric

FURTHER UPDATE: this error has not occurred since the November update.

EDIT:  you may want to read this if your stateful service stops working for no apparent reason.  Typical sign is using WordCount-like app (for example), the service deployment reports that one partition is remaining and after 5 tries gives up.  The stateless service starts ok.  The diagnostics reports multiple "Constructed instance of type WordCountService".   If You have this, then you may have the same problem I have.  No amount of uninstalling VS/SF/Azure SDKs helps.  I now use a VM template with VS/Azure/SF installed and just delete and recreate it each time this error occurs (it is rare but has happened several times).  Assume MSFT is aware and fixing for beta.

ORIGINAL:

Summary question: Is there a way to reset Service Fabric completely?

Background:  I have a stateful/stateless app service based on Wordcount example.  All of a sudden, after deployment the app no longer replicates the stateful service (1 instance, 2 replicas).  The stateless service is deployed ok (one instance, no replicas).

The partition status of the primary partition is reporting "Partition is below target replica or instance count".  The replica status is "InBuild" for replicas, Primary is OK.

On the primary node, there is a warning "Replica had multiple failures during open.  Error = -2147024894.

I have tried cleaning the cluster, uninstalling/reinstalling service fabric, deleting the SfDevCluster directory entirely etc.

If I copy the exact code to another computer with service fabric installed, it works (and I mean copy/paste the whole solution directory).

I had a similar problem last week but it caused the host service not to start.  Tried uninstall/reinstall/clean/remove SDKs, remove Visual Studio, etc.  The only thing that fixed it was a reinstall of windows.